# Chrome console got crashed by using i-- instead of i-1

Tags: javascript, fibonacci

So I was making a program on Fibonacci series finder in javascript whenever i use i-- in the program instead of i-1 console get crashed I am looking for an answer on why it's crashing both i-- and i-1 do the same thing, here's my code:-

```js
function fibonacciGenerator(n) {
  var output = [];
  if (n === 0) {
    return output;
  } else if (n === 1) {
    output.push(0);
    return output;
  } else if (n === 2) {
    output.push(0, 1);
    return output;
  } else {
    output.push(0, 1);
    for (var i = 1; i <= n - 2; i++) {
      output.push(output[i - 1] + output[i]); // Here I was using i-- which caused crash
    }
    return output;
  }
}
```

Comment: This can be related with `i--` returns the value of `i` and, in next step execute the `-` operator, so, your value of `i` receives `-1`. This happens by the precedence operator. In case of `i-1`, the value received in your for will be `i-1` in fact.

Answer (score 3):

Let's take a look at a for loop using `i--`:

```js
for (var i = 1 ; i <= VAL ; i++) {
  i--;
}
```

First time into loop, i is set to 1, then `i--` sets i to 0, then for loop sets it to 1, then `i--` sets i to 0, and so forth.

You have an infinite loop.

Comment: i - - was used in the array index will it still going to decrement the real value of i  by 1? btw I understand the answer thanks for the help.

Comment: @Samst Yes, `i--` will decrement the value of i, no matter where the code is located. It's generally a bad idea to modify a for loop index (as you've discovered).

Comment: Yeah my teacher also used (array.length - 1) in her solution(udemy course) where i is used next time i will always keep this thing in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

If you use i--, the old value will be used for the calculation and the value of i will be decreased by 1 afterward.
But when you use i-1 it's first decreased and that's the value that you look for in output array.

Comment: but then, theoretically, --i should work? I tried here and it did not

Comment: The problem here is that this becomes infinity loop because of i--

Comment: --i would work but still is a bad solution because we get infinity loop

Comment: Yes, that is what i noted too

Answer (score 1):

i-- is the same as i = i - 1
i-1 is an equation, u need it to equal something

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the decrement of i inside that `for` leads to an infitiny loop. However, if you just use i's value and subtract 1, you are not assigning any new value to i.